# Kendo Grid Angular (kendo-angular-grid@^1.4.1)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Currently, I want to select the first row in Kendo Grid. Here is my code:
in Component:

```
export class SampleComponent{  
  gridView: GridDataResult; 
  mySelection: number[] = [0]; 
  state: State = { skip: 0, take: 6, sort: [{ dir: "desc", field: "id" }]};
  ...  
}
```

In HTMl:

```
<kendo-grid id="grid" 
   [data]="gridView" [pageSize]="state.take" 
   [skip]="state.skip" [selectable]="true" 
   (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)" 
   (sortChange)="sortChange($event)" 
   [sort]="state.sort" [filter]="state.filter" 
   [sortable]="true" [kendoGridSelectBy]="'id'" 
   [selectedKeys]="mySelection" [height]="'auto'" [scrollable]="'none'">
```

My issue is: the first row of Grid is not selected. How do i workaround with it?

Please help me.

Comment: update html: <kendo-grid id="grid" [data]="gridView" [pageSize]="state.take" [skip]="state.skip" [selectable]="true" (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)" (sortChange)="sortChange($event)" [sort]="state.sort" [filter]="state.filter" [sortable]="true" [kendoGridSelectBy]="'id'" [selectedKeys]="mySelection" [height]="'auto'" [scrollable]="'none'">

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to select by rowIndex, but you are supplying a key ( 'id') to [kendGridSelectBy], overriding the default.

Change

```
    [kendoGridSelectBy]="'id'"
```

to

```
    kendoGridSelectBy
```

and it should select